# ¿por que se mueve mi mapa de posición, cada vez que cargo la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, openlayers

Buen día compañeros :).

Estoy trabajando con OpenLayers para el uso de mapas en una pagina web, todo bien, si muestra el mapa y donde quiero que se muestre y todo. pero tengo un problema, la 1er vez que entro a la pagina todo se muestra correctamente, pero cuando vuelvo a entrar el mapa se mueve, es como si cargara otra vez el mapa (aunque no lo muestre) ej.

1era vez que entro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la 2da vez que entro... me voy al menu de about y regreso al de mapa y se ve asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el mapa se mueve

el código es el siguiente...

**esta es la parte del html**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h2 class="">datos de la universidad</h2>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Nombre</li>
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li>
                Tecnologico Nacional
              </li>
            </ul>
            <li class="list-group-item">¿Dónde esta?</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Carreras</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

**el script para el mapa**

```
<script>
import 'ol/ol.css';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import { Icon, Style } from 'ol/style';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';

const lon = -1;
const lat = 2;

export default {
  mounted() {
    const map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([lon, lat]),
        zoom: 17
      })
    });

    const marcador = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([lon, lat])),
    });

    marcador.setStyle(new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        src: "https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/null/marker--v1.png",
      })
    }));

    const capa = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [marcador],
      }),
    });

    map.addLayer(capa);

  }
};

</script>
```

**y el Style**

```
<style>
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

ustedes que conocen más, ¿será que me puedan auxiliar por favor?
no se donde moverle jejej :c

cualquier ayuda será muy bien recibida.

de antemano y adelantándome muchas gracias.

Comment: cada vez que cargas la pagina se te mueve de posición?

Comment: Y cuando seleccionas la opción about, es una página diferente (navegas a otra URL y el navegador carga una nueva página) o cambias elementos dentro de esta misma página (single-page-application)?

Comment: @Luis... no, cuando recargo la pagina no se mueve ... de hecho todos los que se cargaron extra (por asi decirlo) se quitan

Comment: @Alfabravo si, cuando me muevo a cualquier otro apartado del menu se va a otra direccion

Comment: Hm. Creo que es necesario que amplíes un poco más la info. SUena a conflicto entre cosas, pero con lo que está en la pregunta es difícil identificarlo. Lo otro es que revises en las herramientas de desarrollo, cuál es el estilo que se está aplicando al elemento `map` en cada caso para que puedas buscar qué estilo está arruinando todo (o qué elemento HTML está mostrándose y no debería)

Comment: @Alfabravo viendo ... el problema es el la otra parte del col-6 donde tengo el texto ... si quito eso el mapa no se duplica... quitando esta parte ya no lo duplica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta estaba aquí ...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h2 class="">datos de la universidad</h2>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Nombre</li>
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li>
                Tecnologico Nacional
              </li>
            </ul>
            <li class="list-group-item">¿Dónde esta?</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Carreras</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

antes tenia un div extra arriba de container, por alguna razón este me movía el mapa cada que regresaba a esa parte por lo que quitando ese div extra, se corrigió el error.